# Content Delivery Java Error 'Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.GetJvmLoader'

Tags: content-delivery, 2013

I just inherited a .NET web project. When running the content delivery side, I couldn't preview the page, receiving the following error:

```
Exception Occured    at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.GetJvmLoader(Int32 ctorVersion, String configFile, String vers, String conf, String reserved, Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, Int32 traceFacility, Int32 traceLevel, Int32& error)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr()
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo)
  at Com.Tridion.Meta.PublicationMetaFactory..ctor()
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.PublicationMetaFactory..ctor()
  at DD4T.Factories.Resolvers.DefaultPublicationResolver.resolvePublicationId(String locale)
```

The website is running in 64 bit with the 64 bit Tridion libraries as well as a 64 bit JVM.

*I wanted to put this out there as I'd searched for this specific error and didn't find it online, other than clues that help lead me to the answer.*

Answer (score 11):

The problem was caused by the single dll file:

> xmogrt.dll

The problem was that somehow my application had the 32 bit version, when I needed to add the 64 bit.

Note: The file size of the 64 version is 1,123kb, the 32bit version is less.

Comment: As an aside, I highly recommend Assembly Information, available on CodePlex. It will put all kinds of useful information at your fingertips when it comes to .NET assemblies (for instance whether it is compiled for the 32 or 64 bit runtime). Get it here: http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/